# IE7 and IE8 randomly not able to load external script

Tags: javascript, css, dom, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am dynamically adding `<link>` elements to the head once the DOM is ready. However, I'm getting inconsistent results in IE8 and IE7 (all other browsers are fine).

Every few times the page is loaded (cached or uncached), IE 7/8 will drop a handful of CSS rules in the stylesheets. <strike>1 or 2 of my dynamic stylesheets will not load. It's always the same 1 or 2 stylesheets that IE tends to ignore - *even though the Developer Toolbar shows them as added to the head!*</strike>.

The stylesheets themselves show up as `<link>` elements in the final DOM, but some of their rules are *not* applied (although every few reloads they are applied, without any issue).

In my position, I do not have the luxury of writing code from the `<head>` (CMS restriction) - I can only dynamically insert from the body, which may be the issue.

**UPDATED:** This is the code I am using (located within the `<body>`) to insert stylesheets:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() { // Using Prototype.js

// Add stylesheets
// addStylesheet('cite.css', 'head'); // Contains no webfont/@font-face rules
// addStylesheet('type.css', 'head'); // Contains webfont family name references*
// addStylesheet('flex.css', 'head'); // Responsive rules with @media queries
// addStylesheet('anm8.css', 'head'); // Some minor positional CSS for home page
// addStylesheet('gothic-cite.css', 'head'); // *Contains @font-face config
// addStylesheet('stag-cite.css', 'head'); // *Contains @font-face config

addStylesheet('all.css', 'head'); // Contains ALL content from above in 1 file

function addStylesheet(cssname, pos2)
{
    var th2 = document.getElementsByTagName(pos2)[0];
    var s2 = document.createElement('link');
    s2.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    s2.setAttribute('href', cssname);
    s2.setAttribute('media', 'screen');
    s2.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    th2.appendChild(s2);
}

});
```

As suggested, even when I combined all rules into one stylesheet (which I hate doing), IE 7/8 continues to flip-flop as described with some rules, and the page appears differently.

As a further check, I also removed all `@font-face` and referenced `font-family: "webfont-name"` rules from the stylesheets, and the same behavior continued. Therefore, **we can rule out webfonts being the issue**.

You can see the anomalies by visiting the following with IE8 and refreshing/clicking the nav several times. It seems completely random as to when IE8 is dropping those styles. However, in the natively-built control page, all styles load correctly, every time.

### Live Page (with problems)

https://www.eiseverywhere.com/ehome/index.php?eventid=31648&tabid=50283

1. PHP-based CMS prints out XHTML on page load (template content mixed w/user content)
2. `Prototype.js` is loaded and initialized by default on page load
3. CMS proprietary `scripts.js` file is parsed on page load
4. My scripts run when DOM is loaded, essentially replacing `body.innerHTML` CMS fluff-HTML with just the HTML I want, **then** adds stylesheets to `<head>`.
5. For `lte IE 8`, CSS extension plugins (selectivizr.js, html5.js, and ie-media-queries.js) are loaded within the `<body>` via conditional comments. Not sure if they wait for `DOM:loaded`...
6. The **CMS WYSIWYG editor converts all carriage-returns to empty `<p>` tags**, resulting in elements like `<section>` being contained inside broken `<p>` tags, and extra `<p></p>` tags being created where whitespace is expected. Only `lt IE 8` seems to choke on this, however, so I added the following CSS rules to remedy this:

   ```
   :not(.ie7) p { display: none; }
   .ie7 p { display: inline; }
   article p { display: block !important; }
   ```
7. I should note that the external stylesheets here are being pulled from the same domain, but each time they are re-uploaded, a new MD5-based URL is generated for the file. I'm not sure if previous revisions to the file (or previous files) are still available by their previous URLs. This isn't likely to be the problem though, since the newly created `all.css` stylesheet is still dropping rules that have been in the file from the start.

### Control Page (works flawlessly)

http://client.clevelanddesign.com/CD/IDG/CITE/home.html

1. Pure XHTML document - no PHP.
2. jQuery is used, rather than Prototype, for IE8 and below.
3. All resources (stylesheets) are present in `<head>` at page load - no dynamic insertion
4. For `lte IE 8`, CSS extension plugins (selectivizr.js, html5.js, and ie-media-queries.js) are initialized natively.

### Rephrased question:

Which of these differences do you think may be causing IE 7/8 to flip-flop on styles when loaded on the Live page? I personally suspect either a race-condition issue, or that `Prototype.js` and the other CMS scripts are mucking things up (unfortunately no way to purge those from the page though).

PS: I've already tried using IE's `createStylsheet()` function, to no avail.

**UPDATE - Screenshots of working/not working in IE8**

IE8: DOM code when loaded correctly:
[image: IE8: DOM code when loaded correctly]

IE8: DOM code when **NOT** loaded correctly:
[image: IE8: DOM code when NOT loaded correctly]

Comment: Maybe something in here will help:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/10164546.aspx

Comment: I checked and with all the stylesheets combined, I am only using about 200 rules between those external stylesheets not nearly close to any of the 32-bit limitations. So that's not it :/

Comment: I suspect that it's an issue with certain rules and not the sheets themselves.  It would be an interesting test:  Combine `type.css` and `flex.css` into `cite.css` and see if anything is different.  It should work exactly the same.

Comment: @Sparky672 - I combined all of my stylesheets into one all.css, and I've noticed two interesting things. 1: All the rules are now loading perfectly, from every originally separate CSS file. 2: The webfont rules (`@font-face {...}`) and rules that reference the `font-family` names given therein are not present 50% of the time, and follow the same inconsistent loading pattern with IE 7/8 as described in the question above. 1: Shouldn't combining them have had no impact on IE's choice to apply the rules? 2: Why is IE dropping the `@font-face` rules every so often?

Comment: IE is garbage; plus I tend to stay away from imported fonts because of weird issues like this.  I think your test conclusively points to your embedded fonts.   If I knew with more certainty, I'd post an answer below... right now it's just IMHO.

Comment: I want to say there are two issues here: IE having a race-condition kind of problem with multiple, dynamically added stylesheets; and IE having an issue applying `@font-face` rules. But before I confirm that the two are unrelated issues, I want to test how the multiple stylesheets (as originally configured) work when all `@font-face` rules have been removed (for testing purposes). If I can get consistent page loads in IE (where *all* non-`@font-face` styles get applied), then I can say that these two issues stem from the same `@font-face` discrepancy (in which case I'd change this Q's title).

Comment: I think you're on to it.  For what it's worth, I also had quite a few problems getting those IE specific JavaScript crutches to play nice with my jQuery stuff.  I stopped supporting IE 6 entirely and IE 7 & below gets a notification that their browser is out of date.  I focus my energies on IE 8+ with much less concern about how the site looks in IE 7.  IMHO, you can have a site look fantastic for 90% while still perfectly functional for 98% of your visitors; or you can have a slow, bloated, ordinary looking site work exactly the same for 99.99% of your visitors.

Comment: All - I've listed out the key differences between the working page setup and the live, problematic page setup. Hopefully this gives you all a better view of the situation.

Comment: Does the HTML [validate](http://validator.w3.org/)?  IE can get funky and slip into quirks-mode when the HTML is not perfect.

Comment: Besides inline script and IE filter CSS, the page is mostly valid. However, I don't think that would cause IE8 to load the page perfectly 50% of the time, and not the other 50% of the time.

Comment: and calling addStylesheet below (after) the function is declared doesn't help? just an idea... i feel sorry for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've nailed down exactly *what* is happening, but still do not know the cause of flip-flop:

`selectivizr.js` is not loading correctly every few page loads.

All of the rules that use CSS3 selectors need that script to be applied in IE 7/8. Therefore when IE 7/8 does not load `selectivizr.js` correctly, those rules are ignored. Those rules certainly include the webfont references, as well as the errant `<p>` display properties.

To remind you all, these helper JS scripts are being loaded normally (from within the `<body>`) with the initial page load, before my script replaces the `<body>` contents (*including that script reference*). Therefore, there's a chance it's initializing twice (can anyone confirm this?)

The trouble is, on the control website, `selectivizr.js` *always* loads correctly in IE 7/8. There are also no known incompatibilities between the CSS3 helper js and the Media Query help js files (when initialized correctly).

I removed `selectivizr.js` from the page and the page loaded exactly the same way after 20+ refreshes. Good to get consistency back, bad that I've lost my CSS3 rules in IE 7/8.

Apparently this is how the js plugin in question works:

> In accordance with the W3C specs, a web browser should discard style
>   rules it doesn’t understand. This presents a problem — we need access
>   to the CSS3 selectors in the style sheet but IE throws them away. To
>   avoid this issue each style sheet is downloaded using a
>   XMLHttpRequest. This allows the script to bypass the browsers internal
>   CSS parser and gain access to the raw CSS file.

Source: http://www.css3.info/css3-pseudo-selectors-emulation-in-internet-explorer/

I can try any suggested CSS3-selector plugins that you all may have; maybe one will load more reliable, or have less overhead and thus less room for lag-related issues. Any alternatives?

<strike>Or, perhaps I should add it *after* the DOM is ready the second time (after my script replaces the body contents) to the `<head>` or elsewhere in the `<body>`.</strike> *None of these options worked - they had the same if not worse outcome*.

Comment: Using JS at all to insert the `selectivizr.js` script seems to break the page completely. Only seems to work when naturally parsed as content within the `<body>` element. Hmm.

Answer (score -1):

First off let me say I have worked on multiple initiatives where the teams have started down the path of dynamically generating the DOM via Javascript, including remote-loading of scripts through CORS.

After many months of effort on 3 different projects (and different approaches used in each), we finally had to face the fact that IE7 and IE8 are incapable of properly or consistently dynamically loading and processing external scripts or CSS.

**My recommendation is to consolidate / combine any scripts on the PHP / server side and serve up as a single file that can be cached on the client side.**

As an additional note, IE is not completely to blame. There are huge complexities involved with downloading, processing, and rendering scripts / css in the correct orders and programming this process such that it works well in every environment (webkit + mozilla + IE9+) requires near-expert-level knowledge and very thorough testing.

In your case, one example of bad "flow" is the fact that when I viewed your page specifically, it briefly shows the non-CSS-applied page (yucky!) before the screen "updates" and CSS gets pulled in and applied. Bad bad bad.

Other issues I noticed are the large number of httprequests in general. Each requires a DNS lookup, cache / expires check (and other stuff dictated by headers), and subsequent download of response. On desktops this is not all that noticable, but on mobile devices, tablets and even some slower / bogged-down PC's it is especially noticable.

If you're building a web app in today's browsing environment and have only a small team, it's probably best to either:

1. Serve up CSS as a single, cacheable file from a CDN, and pages in pre-parsed, pre-iterated, pre-rendered HTML chunks, minimizing the client-side JS processing (only binding elements post-load), or
2. Go with a pre-existing client-side framework such as Sencha, SproutCore, YUI etc. - they have built out the framework for you and fixed all the bugs already.

Two things have to happen before I change my view: IE8 has to disappear from general use (drops below 10%), and the "average" mobile device needs to have 2 physical processor cores. Right now only the expensive / high-end models have dual-core processors.

Also of note, the fastest mobile processors even with JIT JS compilers are still 10x slower than a typical desktop in JS performance - which when compared directly to a desktop, would compete head-to-head with a Pentium 4 or old AMD Athlon 64.

Comment: I completely agree that I *should* be spitting all of these stylesheets and scripts out at once, server-side, but I simply cannot because I am but a small client of this large CMS platform/company, and they are not likely to allow me to edit the template or make a special case for these nodes. In fact, my first test when I found out my limits was a `<?PHP>` command that simply printed everything exactly as it appeared in the control page source.

Comment: (Using PHP was obviously disallowed on this CMS, unfortunately)

Comment: Remote loading and execution of external scripts work just fine in IE7 and 8. There are plenty of working script loaders out there. Sure you're not mixing external with cross-origin? IE7/8 doesn't support CORS. They have XDomainRequest, but with many problems.

Comment: @gregers "work just fine" is false. The specific case is applying scripts by appending <link> tags to the <head>. There are multiple issues in various scenarios / environments where IE7 and IE8 fail to work correctly. The challenge atwixtor is likely facing is dealing with a plethora of scripts that may attempt to do the same / similar things on page load. All kinds of potential for conflicts.